# Exercicio com problema no contador

Tags: c

O exercicio precisa ser feito com while ou do while, em linguagem C..

> A prefeitura de uma cidade fez uma pesquisa entre seus habitantes, coletando dados sobre o salário e número de filhos. A prefeitura deseja saber: 
>   a) média do salário da população;
>   b) média do número de filhos;
>   c) maior salário;d) percentual de pessoas com salário até R$ 100,00.
>   O final da leitura de dados se dará com a entrada de um salário negativo.

o código inteiro está funcionando no geral, porém quando aparece os resultados, o número que eu coloquei para encerrar o loop é somado junto, o erro provavelmente está no `contador_pessoas++;`, porém eu já tentei colocar dentro de um `if`, mas ai quando eu digito números menores que 100 o programa não roda e encerra..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int filhos=0, contador_pessoas=0, contador_pessoas_100;
float salario=0, media_salario=0, media_filhos=0, porcentagem_salario=0, maior_salario=0, porcentagem=0;

main()
{
    do
    {
        printf("Digite o seu salario(para encerrar digite um salario negativo): ");
        scanf("%f", &salario);
            contador_pessoas++;
            media_salario = media_salario + salario;

        if(salario <= 100){
            contador_pessoas_100++;
            porcentagem = (contador_pessoas_100*100)/contador_pessoas;
        }

        if(salario>maior_salario){
            maior_salario = salario;
        }else if(salario < 0){
            break;
        }

        printf("Digite o numero de filhos: ");
        scanf("%d", &filhos);
        media_filhos = media_filhos + filhos;

    }while(1);

    printf("A media do salario da populacao e: %0.2f\n", media_salario/contador_pessoas);
    printf("A media do numero de filhos da populacao e: %0.1f\n", media_filhos/contador_pessoas);
    printf("O maior salario e: %0.2f\n", maior_salario);
    printf("A porcentagem de pessoas com salario ate 100 reais e de: %0.1f\n", porcentagem);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Após a leitura você precisa testar se o salário é não negativo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int filhos=0, contador_pessoas=0, contador_pessoas_100=0;
float salario=0, media_salario=0, media_filhos=0, porcentagem_salario=0, maior_salario=0, porcentagem=0;

int main()
{
    do
    {
        printf("Digite o seu salario(para encerrar digite um salario negativo): ");
        scanf("%f", &salario);
        if (salario >= 0) {
            contador_pessoas++;
            media_salario = media_salario + salario;
            if(salario <= 100){
                contador_pessoas_100++;
            }

            if(salario>maior_salario){
                maior_salario = salario;
            }
            printf("Digite o numero de filhos: ");
            scanf("%d", &filhos);
            media_filhos = media_filhos + filhos;
        }
        else
            break;
    }while(1);
    porcentagem = ((float) contador_pessoas_100*100)/contador_pessoas;
    printf("A media do salario da populacao e: %0.2f\n", media_salario/contador_pessoas);
    printf("A media do numero de filhos da populacao e: %0.1f\n", media_filhos/contador_pessoas);
    printf("O maior salario e: %0.2f\n", maior_salario);
    printf("A porcentagem de pessoas com salario ate 100 reais e de: %0.1f\n", porcentagem);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So que com isso na parte da porcentagem esta agora sempre dando um valor de 100, voce sabe pq?

Comment: Corrigido a inicialização do contador e o local do cálculo da percentagem. Seria conveniente testar se foi informado algum salário válido (contador_pessoas > 0) antes de calcular a percentagem. Note que você também está fazendo uma operação entre inteiros e portanto o resultado será inteiro mas quando vai imprimir pressupõe que seja um float. Use cast para forçar a operação em ponto flutuante.